# how to move the top of the doughnut chart labels to the side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, primeng

I'm developing a dashboard using a primeng module . I had a doughnut chart with labels and the labels were placed on top of the doughnut chart. Now I need labels to place them on the side.

[image: image link]

Could you please guide me on this thing.

My code :

```
this.inspectionStorageBarChart = {

              labels: ['Completed', 'Due', 'Pending', 'Deficient', 'Report'],

              datasets: [

                {

                  data: [],

                  backgroundColor: [

                    'green',

                    '#51087E',

                    '#ffd740',

                    'red',

                    '#5500FF',

                  ],

                },

              ],

            };

            this.pieOptions = {

              plugin: {

                legend: {

                  labels: { position: 'right' },

                },

              },

            };
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=primeng+chart+move+labels+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.